# xkeyval declaring package option keys that are choice keys or boolkeys

Tags: xkeyval

`xkeyval` provides `\DeclareOptionX` which effectively defines a key like `\define@key` does but that can be used as a package option.

How can I `\DeclareOptionX`s that behave like `\define@choicekey` or `\define@boolkey` would?

I've done the following, but it isn't ideal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\newcounter{testcounter}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testpackage.sty}
\define@boolkey{testpackage}{ffoo}{}
\DeclareOptionX{foo}{\setkeys{testpackage}{ffoo=#1}}
\ProcessOptionsX
\ifKV@testpackage@ffoo
\def\foo{Foo}
\else
\def\foo{Fail}
\fi
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[foo=true]{testpackage}
\begin{document}
\foo
\end{document}
```

This isn't great since the error doesn't refer to the key it *should* refer to, that is, to the key that the user sets.

Is there some obvious way of doing this that I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to use `\DeclareOptionX` to set up options using `xkeyval`. As with any other keyval package for LaTeX, anything which is set up as a key will work as an option for the appropriate family. Thus you can use `\define@choicekey` or `\define@boolkey` directly:

```
\define@choicekey*{fam}{key}{val1,Val2,VAL3}{You chose: #1}
\ProcessOptionsX<fam>
```

makes `key` available as a choice key when loading the package or class the code is contained in.

Comment: Huh. I was fairly sure I tried exactly this and it didn't work! It does work now. I wonder what I was doing wrong... [Also, isn't it `\DeclareOptionX` not `\DefineOptionX`?]